# Define 2D matrix with non-zero elements only in a rectangular subregion

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, sparse-matrix

Given two specified dimensions `N1` and `N2`, and some boundaries `ymin, ymax, xmin, xmax`, I want to build an `N1xN2` matrix (be it a numpy array or a plain python list) which is zero everywhere, except in a rectangular subregion specified by its boundaries.

To be more precise, I'm looking for how to implement a function `rectangular_sparse_matrix(N1, N2, ymin, ymax, xmin, xmax)` such that, for example,

```
N1 = N2 = 5
rectangular_sparse_matrix(N1, N2, 0, 2, 1, 2)
```

returns

```
[[ 0  1  1  0  0]
 [ 0  1  1  0  0]
 [ 0  1  1  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0]]
```

---

The naive way would be to just loop through the elements, like in

```
def rectangular_sparse_matrix(N1, N2, ymin, ymax, xmin, xmax):
    matrix = np.zeros([N1, N2])
    for row in range(N1):
        for col in range(N2):
            if ymin <= row <= ymax and xmin <= col <= xmax:
                matrix[row, col] = 1
    return matrix
```

which does the job.
However, I was wandering if there was some more efficient/easier way to achieve something like this, maybe using some obscure (to me) numpy feature or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def rectangular_sparse_matrix(N1, N2, ymin, ymax, xmin, xmax):
    m = np.zeros([N1, N2])
    m[ymin:ymax+1, xmin:xmax+1] = 1
    return m
```

In the function slicing numpy array is used.